# Month & Year filter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with following columns:

[image: SQL Table]

Now, I have to write query which will return me the records where "Month > May" and "F Year > 2016".

I am providing both "Month" (May) & "F Year" (2016) from my application. There are multiple records with the same Month & F Year column values.

I tried with Date part, Cast etc. but not getting required result.

Comment: *"I tried with Date part, Cast etc. but not getting required result."* >> Please include the query you tried in your question.

Comment: CAST('+Month+','+FYear' AS DATETIME)>CAST('February,2017' AS DATETIME)

Comment: (DATEPART(MM, Month) > DATEPART(MM, 'February'))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this (with month name)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE DATEPART(MM, ([Month] + ' 01 2016'))  > DATEPART(MM,'May' + ' 01 2016') 
  AND FYear > 2016
```

or that (with month number)

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE DATEPART(MM, ([Month] + ' 01 2016'))  > 5
  AND FYear > 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : This is just specific for your current requirment

```
...
FROM TableName
WHERE [Month] NOT IN ('January','February','March','April') AND FYear >= 2016
```

Comment: The OP said that the month is coming from the application but this code will not handle arbitrary date

Comment: @mendosi you are right. but I think you didn't  see my Ans heading that makes thing pretty cleared

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @month varchar(20)='may'
set @month=left(@month,3)
select * from tablename  where CONVERT(varchar(3), CAST('Fmonth,Fyear' AS DATETIME), 100)>@month and year>2016
```

Comment: Hi, I can not provide 5 in query since I have only Month name available.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your columns to a date and then do a date comparison as required.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE as (
SELECT 2016 as FYear,'January' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'February' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'March' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'April' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'May' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'June' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'July' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'August' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'September' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'October' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'November' as Month
UNION ALL SELECT 2016 as FYear,'December' as Month
), CTE2 as (
SELECT *,CONVERT(DATE,'01 ' + LEFT(Month,3) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),FYear),106) dt
FROM CTE)
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE dt > '20160401';
```

**Output**

```
FYear   Month   dt
2016    May 2016-05-01
2016    June    2016-06-01
2016    July    2016-07-01
2016    August  2016-08-01
2016    September   2016-09-01
2016    October 2016-10-01
2016    November    2016-11-01
2016    December    2016-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below sql:

```
select A.*
from
(
select 2016 FYear,'September' Month
union
select 2016 FYear,'October' Month
union
select 2016 FYear,'November' Month
union
select 2016 FYear,'December' Month
union
select 2016 FYear,'January' Month
union
select 2016 FYear,'Febraury' Month
union
select 2016 FYear,'March' Month
) A
inner join 
(
select 1 monthno,'January' MonthName
union
select 2 monthno,'February' MonthName
union
select 3 monthno,'March' MonthName
union
select 4 monthno,'April' MonthName
union
select 5 monthno,'May' MonthName
union
select 6 monthno,'June' MonthName
union
select 7 monthno,'July' MonthName
union
select 8 monthno,'August' MonthName
union
select 9 monthno,'September' MonthName
union
select 10 monthno,'October' MonthName
union
select 11 monthno,'November' MonthName
union
select 12 monthno,'December' MonthName
) B on A.Month = B.MonthName
WHERE A.FYear >= 2016 AND B.monthno >3
```